# Obtaining Group Name in Alfresco 4

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am executing a script from a workflow to compile names from a "select group" (docWorkflow_selectgroup) cm:authorityContainer for *mail.parameters.to_many*.

In Alfresco 5.0, I can use the following code:

```
groupArr[0] = docWorkflow_selectgroup.get(0).properties["cm:name"];
mail.parameters.to_many = groupArr;
```

If the first group selected is ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS, this code will set **GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS** as the first element of the array. This is the correct format needed by the *mail.parameters.to_many* parameter.

However, we have another server that is still running Alfresco 4, and this same exact code returns *null* for any amount of groups selected, resulting in the following error:

> org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 07060563 Failed to execute supplied script: All recipients for the mail action were invalid

What changes will allow this code to work in Alfresco 4?